# Why is the destructor called on vector before printing the values in vector in the following code

Tags: c++, vector, destructor

In the following code, the vector loses all its content before calling the print method.
I am assuming the destructor is called before the print statement.
Could anyone let me know why a destructor is called before the object is going out of scope.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;
        class test {
        private:
            vector<int> distance;
        public:
            test();
            void print();
        };
        void test::print() {
            cout << "In Print";
            for (auto itr = distance.begin(); itr != distance.end(); ++itr)
                cout << *itr << "\n";
        }
        test::test() {
            std::vector<int>distance(100, 1);
        }
        int main()
        {
            cout << "executing main \n";
            test t;
            t.print();
            cin.get();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Your distance vector isn't initialized the way you think it is.

Comment: `test::test() {
            std::vector<int>distance(100, 1);
        }` should be `test::test() :
            distance(100, 1) {}`

Comment: The `test::test` constructor only default initializes the instance member variable `distance`.

Comment: @SenselessCoder Could you please elaborate when you meant the disance vector isnt initialized the way i think.

Comment: `std::vector<int>distance(100, 1);` just creates a local variable (with same same as the member).

Comment: [OT]: With for range, `for (auto itr = distance.begin(); itr != distance.end(); ++itr)` might simply be `for (auto e : distance) { std::cout << e << "\n"; }`

Comment: Handy reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Answer (score 4):

```
test::test() {
    std::vector<int>distance(100, 1);
}
```

This will create a new vector local to the constructor, that will be destroyed as soon as the constructor finishes.

To initialize the vector in your class you should use [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

```
test::test() : distance(100,1) {}
```

**Edit**

Another option is to initialize the vector in the class definition.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
    class test {
    private:
        vector<int> distance{5, 7, 9, 12};
    public:
        test();
        void print();
    };
    void test::print() {
        cout << "In Print";
        for (auto itr = distance.begin(); itr != distance.end(); ++itr)
            cout << *itr << "\n";
    }
    int main()
    {
        cout << "executing main \n";
        test t;
        t.print();
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way apart from initializer list to define the data members of a class?For example, i have to assign some value to the data member distance of the test class above.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

The correct way to initialize the member vector in the constructor is:

```
test::test()
: distance(100, 1) // initializes member vector with 100 ones, but
                   // you may use any vector constructor here
{
}
```

This will also work:

```
test::test()
: distance() // this line is implicit if you don't add it
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        distance.push_back(1); // appends 1 to the member distance
    }
}
```

but it is not desirable since it is less efficient because you create and initialize a default empty vector, and then you initialize it again in the body of the constructor. However, depending on what you need to initialize the vector with, it may make sense to do it in the body of the constructor, if the values require calculating, for instance.

For a good reference of std::vector<>, including its constructors, see [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). This vector tutorial that I wrote may also be of use: [C++ std::vector for post-beginners](https://swdevmastery.com/c-stdvector-for-post-beginners-including-real-issues-ive-seen-in-practice-and-surprising-modern-usage-recommendations/).

**YOUR PROBLEM**

Your constructor is creating a new and different vector with the same name in its body. Then, when the destructor is finished, the new vector initialized there goes out of scope, and it is destroyed:

```
test::test()
{
    vector<int> distance(100, 1); // Creates a new vector with the same
                                  // name as your member variable.
} // end of constructor scope; the vector created here is destroyed
```

The constructor above is equivalent to:

```
test::test()
: distance() // default initialization of member distance
{
    vector<int> distance(100, 1); // Creates a new different vector with the
                                  // same name as your member variable.
} // end of constructor scope; the new vector created is destroyed
```